# NBA 7 game playoff series where every game was won by the home team?

Tags: trivia, basketball, nba, postseason

I'm looking for a list of all 7 game playoff series in the NBA history where the home team won every game.

So far I know:

- [2017-2018](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2018_NBA_Playoffs) First Round: Boston Celtics vs Milwaukee Bucks (4-3)
- [2016-2017](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2017_NBA_Playoffs) Conference Semifinals: Boston Celtics vs Washington Wizards (4-3)

Answer (score 2):

1955 [Finals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1955_NBA_Finals): Syracuse Nationals vs Fort Wayne Pistons (4-3)

1965 [Division Finals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1965_NBA_Playoffs): Boston Celtics vs Philadelphia 76ers (4-3)

1971 [Conference Semifinals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1971_NBA_Playoffs):  Los Angeles Lakers vs. Chicago Bulls (4-3)

1973 [Conference Semifinals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1973_NBA_Playoffs): Los Angeles Lakers vs. Chicago Bulls (4-3)

1977 [Conference Semifinals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1977_NBA_Playoffs): Los Angeles Lakers vs. Golden State Warriors (4-3)

1984 [Conference Semifinals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1984_NBA_Playoffs): Boston Celtics vs. New York Knicks (4-3)

1990 [Conference Semifinals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1990_NBA_Playoffs): San Antonio Spurs vs. Portland Trail Blazers (4-3)

1990 [Conference Finals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1990_NBA_Playoffs): Detroit Pistons vs. Chicago Bulls (4-3)

1993 [Conference SemiFinals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1993_NBA_Playoffs):  Houston Rockets vs. Seattle SuperSonics

1994 [Conference SemiFinals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1994_NBA_Playoffs): New York Knicks vs. Chicago Bulls (4-3)

1995 [Conference Finals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1995_NBA_Playoffs):  Orlando Magic vs. Indiana Pacers (4-3)

1998 [Conference Finals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1998_NBA_Playoffs): Chicago Bulls vs. Indiana Pacers (4-3)

2004 [First Round](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2004_NBA_Playoffs): Miami Heat vs. New Orleans Hornets (4-3)

2008 [First Round](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2008_NBA_Playoffs): Boston Celtics vs.  Atlanta Hawks (4-3)

2008 [Conference Semifinals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2008_NBA_Playoffs#(1)_Boston_Celtics_vs._(4)_Cleveland_Cavaliers): Boston Celtics vs. Cleveland Cavaliers (4-3)